# FParsec combinator to turn Parser<char,_> until Parser<string,_>?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm certain there's a really simple answer to this, but I've been staring at this all day and I can't figure it out.

As per the tutorial, I'm implementing a JSON parser. To challenge myself, I'm implementing the `number` parser myself.

This is what I got so far:

```
let jnumber =
    let neg = stringReturn "-" -1 <|> preturn 1
    let digit = satisfy (isDigit)
    let digit19 = satisfy (fun c -> isDigit c && c <> '0')
    let digits = many1 digit
    let ``int`` =
        digit
        <|> (many1Satisfy2 (fun c -> isDigit c && c <> '0') isDigit)
```

The trouble is that `digit` is a `Parser<char,_>`, whereas the second option for `int` is a `Parser<string,_>`. Would I normally just use a combinator to turn `digit` into a `Parser<char,_>`, or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|>>` operator is what you're looking for. I quote [the FParsec reference](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.:124%3a:62%3a:62%3a):

```
val (|>>): Parser<'a,'u> -> ('a -> 'b) -> Parser<'b,'u>
```

> The parser p
>   |>> f applies the parser p and returns the result of the function
>   application f x, where x is the result returned by  p.
>
> p |>> f is an
>   optimized implementation of p >>= fun x -> preturn (f x).

For example:

```
let jnumber =
    let neg = stringReturn "-" -1 <|> preturn 1
    let digit = satisfy (isDigit)
    let digit19 = satisfy (fun c -> isDigit c && c <> '0')
    let digits = many1 digit
    (digit |>> string) (* The operator is used here *)
    <|> (many1Satisfy2 (fun c -> isDigit c && c <> '0') isDigit)
```

You may want to read [FParsec tutorial on parsing JSON](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-json) which uses this operator quite intensively.